# How would I get a taxonomy/category list inside a Gutenberg block?

Tags: categories, ajax, block-editor

I would like to display a dropdown list of categories (or other taxonomy) inside of a Gutenberg block. I can only think of two ways to do this:

1. Create an array of the taxonomy in php and use `wp_localize_script` to make that data available to my block javascript.
2. Use `fetch()`? in the block to reach out to the api at */wp-json/wp/v2/categories/* and get all the categories.

Are one of these the preferred method? Is there some other kind of built-in or better way to do this?

### Edit

As I continue to research this, I learned of another method available in the Gutenberg plugin and presumably available once this editor becomes part of core: [`wp.apiFetch()`](https://wordpress.org/gutenberg/handbook/packages/packages-api-fetch/). Apparently, it's a wrapper around fetch which hides away some of the unnecessary parts. Now I'm wondering if this is the preferred method.

3. Use `wp.apiFetch()` in the block to reach out to the REST api at */wp/v2/categories* and get all the categories.

## The Catch

On first glance, it seems to make more sense to use the apiFetch() function. However, because that's asynchronous, the data doesn't get loaded into the JSX element. I'm not sure how to make that data load into the element.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You don't need `apiFetch` or localization to get a list of all categories. You can do this with the `wp.data` module:

```
wp.data.select('core').getEntityRecords('taxonomy', 'category');
```

See the [Gutenberg Handbook](https://wordpress.org/gutenberg/handbook/designers-developers/developers/data/data-core/) entry on Core Data for more details.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Works like a charm!

Comment: To get only the list of selected terms, use `wp.data.select( 'core/editor' ).getEditedPostAttribute( 'my-taxonomy-slug' )`

Comment: found a nice tutorial https://rudrastyh.com/gutenberg/get-posts-in-dynamic-select-control.html which handles `getEntityRecords()`

Comment: And to get a list of currently selected categories: `wp.data.select('core/editor').getEditedPostAttribute('categories')` which will return an array of selected IDs

Answer (score 2):

Load the elements into a constant using a function like this:

```
const postSelections = [];

const allPosts = wp.apiFetch({path: "/wp/v2/posts"}).then(posts => {
    postSelections.push({label: "Select a Post", value: 0});
    $.each( posts, function( key, val ) {
        postSelections.push({label: val.title.rendered, value: val.id});
    });
    return postSelections;
});
```

Then use postSelections as your element "options".

```
                    el(
                        wp.components.SelectControl,
                        {
                            label: __('Select a Post'),
                            help: 'Select a post to display as a banner.',
                            options: postSelections,
                            value: selectedPost,
                            onChange: onChangePost
                        }
                    ),
```

Comment: Thanks Chad. Have you done it this way? If so, have you found that the data gets loaded _before_ the element is rendered? I was running into an issue where the data was not getting loaded in time, and so wasn't "connected" to the element.

Comment: Indeed!  If you load it before the edit: part, it gets loaded with the page before the elements are rendered.  The constants are the FIRST thing in your block js file.  Before you even use registerBlockType you define the constants and give them value.

Comment: Also be aware that if you want to use wp.apiFetch in your js file, you need to load the wp-api-fetch file in your PHP file when registering scripts (wp_register_script).  See my post here https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/320483/uncaught-typeerror-wp-apifetch-is-not-a-function/320488#320488

Comment: Did this actually work for anyone? I've implemented a similar approach to no avail. Promises are resolved asynchronously so I'm not sure how this would prevent the editor from being loaded.

Comment: @LukeKeller it works for me on production sites.

Comment: Interesting @ChadHolden! I ended up abandoning the approach entirely and going a different direction. If I _were_ to do this again (assuming I would fail then as well), I'd look into creating a custom Component to render the select dropdown. Hope that helps anyone who is struggling to get this to work!