# Uncaught TypeError: wp.apiFetch is not a function

Tags: block-editor

I'm working with the latest Gutenberg and WP and until last week, the code below worked as expected.

```
const postSelections = [];

const allPosts = wp.apiFetch({path: "/wp/v2/featured-post"}).then(fps => {
    postSelections.push({label: "Select a Post", value: 0});
    $.each( fps, function( key, val ) {
        postSelections.push({label: val.title.rendered, value: val.id});
    });
    return postSelections;
});
```

All of a sudden I'm getting wp.apiFetch is not a function errors.

Anyone have any idea why??

Comment: It looks like you are not adding the `wp-api-fetch` dependency in your script.

Comment: I'm loading that through the PHP end:

    wp_register_script(
  'featured-post-block-block-editor',
  plugins_url( $index_js, __FILE__ ),
  array(
   'wp-blocks',
   'wp-i18n',
   'wp-element',
   'wp-api',
  ),
  filemtime( "$dir/$index_js" )
    );

Comment: Add also `'wp-api-fetch'` and it should not throw the error.

Comment: Winner winner, chicken dinner!  Submit it as an answer if you want credit.  The change from wp-api to wp-api-fetch worked.  Odd though because up until version Gutenberg 4.4 wp-api alone worked.

Comment: Things have been changing much last months in Gutenberg, it was a bit difficult sometimes to follow up, but it is already in RC. My suggestion is to check the code repository rather than the documentation, at least for the moment, until code is in official final stage and documentation gets fully updated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as @Alvero pointed out in the comments, instead of just supplying wp-api in the block registration, you now need to specify wp-api-fetch.

```
$index_js = 'sample-post/index.js';
wp_register_script(
    'sample-post-block-block-editor',
    plugins_url( $index_js, __FILE__ ),
    array(
        'wp-blocks',
        'wp-i18n',
        'wp-element',
        'wp-api-fetch',
    ),
    filemtime( "$dir/$index_js" )
);
```

Then within your block, you call it using the wp.apiFetch function:

```
var registerBlockType = wp.blocks.registerBlockType,
    el = wp.element.createElement,
    __ = wp.i18n.__,
    apiFetch = wp.apiFetch;

const postSelections = [];

const allPosts = apiFetch({path: "/wp/v2/featured-post"}).then(fps => {
    postSelections.push({label: "Select a Post", value: 0});
    $.each( fps, function( key, val ) {
        postSelections.push({label: val.title.rendered, value: val.id});
    });
    return postSelections;
});
```