# How to return a list of custom taxonomy terms via the Gutenberg getEntityRecords method

Tags: custom-taxonomy, taxonomy, block-editor

This method for @SE [How would I get a taxonomy/category list inside a Gutenberg block?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/319035/how-would-i-get-a-taxonomy-category-list-inside-a-gutenberg-block/336924#336924) does NOT work for custom taxonomies, e.g.:

```
wp.data.select('core').getEntityRecords('taxonomy', 'my-custom-taxonomy', {per_page: -1})
```

and only returns null, whereas the core category, i.e. "category", returns:

```
wp.data.select('core').getEntityRecords('taxonomy', 'category', {per_page: -1})
```

returns an entire array of taxonomy term data such as:

- count
- description
- id
- link
- meta []
- name
- parent
- slug
- taxonomy
  etc.

The official docs at: https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/data/data-core/#getEntityRecords are woefully lacking, and whilst there are references to the "getEntityRecords" in GitHub at e.g.: https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/04e142e9cbd06a45c4ea297ec573d389955c13be/packages/core-data/src/entities.js there is little in the way of documentation to help!

So here is the question:

**How can you return the list of custom taxonomies using the wp.data.select('core').getEntityRecords method?**

OR do you need to create a custom store, or use the wp.data Backbone JS?

Answer (score 3):

1. The `getEntityRecords()` method [uses the REST API](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/04e142e9cbd06a45c4ea297ec573d389955c13be/packages/core-data/src/resolvers.js#L60), so make sure the taxonomy is enabled for the REST API. You can enable it via the `show_in_rest` parameter when registering the taxonomy using [`register_taxonomy()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_taxonomy/).
2. With `getEntityRecords()`, if you set `per_page` to `-1`, it will actually be changed to `100`, which as you've figured it out, is the max number of results returned for a single API request (details [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/pagination/#pagination-parameters)). Hence that's why `per_page: -1` *should* work *with `getEntityRecords()`*.
3. Any AJAX/remote requests would not give you *immediate* results and we would need to wait a moment until the browser receives the response from the server. So this is probably the actual reason to why you're not getting any results immediately upon first call to `getEntityRecords()`.

With that said, on subsequent calls (for the same query), you should get immediate results because `getEntityRecords()` cache the results (for performance reasons — you wouldn't want each call to `getEntityRecords()` takes several *seconds* to give you the results, would you?).

So try:

1. [`wp.apiFetch()`](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/tree/master/packages/api-fetch) which is used by `getEntityRecords()`: Both these work; `apiFetch()` makes request to `http://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/your_tax?per_page=100`:

   ```js
   wp.apiFetch( { path: '/wp/v2/your_tax?per_page=-1' } )
       // 'terms' contains valid term objects
       .then( terms => console.log( terms ) );

   wp.apiFetch( { path: '/wp/v2/your_tax?per_page=100' } )
       // 'terms' contains valid term objects
       .then( terms => console.log( terms ) );
   ```
2. [`fetch()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) which is used internally by `wp.apiFetch()`:

   ```js
   fetch( '/wp-json/wp/v2/your_tax?per_page=-1' )
       .then( res => res.json() )
       // 'terms' contains an error about per_page should be between 1 and 100
       .then( terms => console.log( terms ) );

   fetch( '/wp-json/wp/v2/your_tax?per_page=100' )
       .then( res => res.json() )
       // 'terms' contains valid term objects
       .then( terms => console.log( terms ) );
   ```

So if you make manual requests to `/wp-json/wp/v2/your_tax` (i.e. a taxonomy terms REST API), then you should not set the `per_page` to `-1`. But with `wp.apiFetch()` and functions which uses `apiFetch()` like `getEntityRecords()`, you *can* use that `-1` although you should *not*…

Answer (score 1):

**ANSWER UPDATE:** IF you have a large number of terms within your taxonomy, i.e. more than 100, you will need to add a {per_page: 100} args limiter in order NOT to get an empty array back, as you will if you try getting ALL results back, i.e. per_page: -1

so you will need something like:

```
wp.data.select('core').getEntityRecords('taxonomy', 'my-custom-taxonomy', {per_page: 100})
```

and that is the maximum on a single API call, although you can then append a "paging" arg, e.g.:

`{per_page: 100, page: 2}`

Comment: As you mentioned below, the initial call in Chrome at least returns an empty array - on 2nd request the test taxonomy did indeed return the expected array, even with the "per_page: -1" arg set - that seems to return an empty array when there are more than 100 results, although there is no warning / error message

Comment: I think the re-posted answer can help you better understand the empty array thing. I also rolled back your answer to your previous revision, but I'm keeping the +1 because the answer does have a valid point there. :)