# Get current tag list in Gutenberg save function

Tags: tags, block-editor

I am trying to get the current tag list for a given post inside the save function to render on page.

There is a similar Q here: [How to return a list of custom taxonomy terms via the Gutenberg getEntityRecords method](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/352323/how-to-return-a-list-of-custom-taxonomy-terms-via-the-gutenberg-getentityrecords), but I am not sure if that is the solution to my problem?

This taxonomy is set to `'show_in_rest' => TRUE,`.

A couple of attempts I have tried are:

```
save: function() {

  // #1:
  var tag_array = wp.data.select("core/editor").getCurrentPostAttribute("custom_taxonomy");
  var tag_list = [];
  if (tag_array) {
    tag_array.forEach(
      tag => tag_list.push(
        el('li', null, wp.data.select('core').getEntityRecord('taxonomy', 'custom_taxonomy', tag))
      ),
    );
  }

  // #2:
  const tag_array = wp.data.select("core/editor").getCurrentPostAttribute("custom_taxonomy");
  const tag_objects = wp.data.select('core').getEntityRecords('taxonomy', 'custom_taxonomy', tag_array);
  var tag_list = [];
  tag_objects.forEach(
    tag => tag_list.push(
      el('li', null, tag.name)
    )
  );
}
```

Attempt **#1** returns objects

Attempt **#2** does not filter the results to the given current tag ID's and returns the entire list of tags in the taxonomy.

`wp.data.select("core/editor").getCurrentPostAttribute("custom_taxonomy");` returns the correct tag ID's.

Is there a method to load a tag name with the ID (other than `.getEntityRecord()`)?

A bit unsure what I'm missing here, how can I get a list of selected tags for the current post?

Answer (score 1):

> Attempt **#1** returns objects

If I understand it correctly, that's because `getEntityRecord()`, upon successful request to the REST API endpoint (e.g. [`/wp/v2/categories/<id>`](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/categories/#retrieve-a-category)), returns the term *object*/data which contains term properties such as name and ID.

So,

```js
// Instead of:
el('li', null, wp.data.select('core').getEntityRecord('taxonomy', 'custom_taxonomy', tag))

// you'd use: (note the ".name")
el('li', null, wp.data.select('core').getEntityRecord('taxonomy', 'custom_taxonomy', tag).name)
```

> Attempt **#2** does not filter the results to the given current tag
> ID's and returns the entire list of tags in the taxonomy.

The third parameter for `getEntityRecords()` is actually an object with the [parameters listed here](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/categories/#arguments) such as `include` for limiting the result set to specific (term) IDs, so in the case of your "Attempt #2", you can do so to limit the results to the given term IDs:

```js
const tag_objects = wp.data.select('core').getEntityRecords('taxonomy', 'custom_taxonomy', {
    include: tag_array
});
```

However, it should be noted that because `getEntityRecord()` and `getEntityRecords()` perform an AJAX request, they don't immediately return the result or response from the server, so don't expect something like `const term = getEntityRecord( 'taxonomy', ... ); console.log( term.name );` to (always) work because the `term` could be an `undefined` (or something else) and not the term object/data.

Secondly, instead of returning the tags/terms as elements in your `save` callback, how about using [dynamic block](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/tutorials/block-tutorial/creating-dynamic-blocks/) whereby you'd use an attribute to save the term IDs and then use PHP to output the HTML on the front-end side? That way, when any of the terms get updated after the post is edited, the displayed term data on the front-end would also be updated without having to first edit the post (which then updates the block output, i.e. the `save` output).

But that is just a suggestion. :)