# How to display post categories within the Latest Posts block?

Tags: categories, block-editor, core

I'm trying to display the category/categories from each post within the Latest Posts block in the WordPress editor.

This post seems to provide some solutions, however I am unsure how to use this helpful answer -
"wp.data.select('core').getEntityRecords('taxonomy', 'category');"

[How would I get a taxonomy/category list inside a Gutenberg block?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/319035/how-would-i-get-a-taxonomy-category-list-inside-a-gutenberg-block)

A helpful guide would be much appreciated.

Comment: This is still relevant and needed. I had to create a separate, new block just to have latest posts displayed with category, which is pretty bad and confusing user experience, but I was not able to figure out elegant way to hook into "Post meta settings" of the core "Latest Posts" to add "Display categories" toggle, and to each post in the loop to render categories.